# Angularjs get attribute using id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table **Plates**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "plate_types_id": 1,
    "project_id": 1,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2015-10-21 18:42:26",
    "updated_at": "2015-10-21 18:57:27"
}
```

and another table in db called **platetypes**

```
"data": {
        "PlateTypes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Sibyl Streich",
                "description": "Necessitatibus.",
                "document_id": 7,
                "created_at": "2015-10-21 18:42:25",
                "updated_at": "2015-10-21 18:42:25"
            }
```

What I want is when I select A plate, I can get the `plate_type_id` as well, but instead of seeing an `id` I want to retrieve the name of the `plate_type` which is in this case the fake data `"Sibyl Streich"`

In my html I have the following.

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select a plate:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <select class="form-control m-b-sm" id="plateId"  ng-model="selectedPlate.item" ng-options="plate as (plate.id + ' - ' + plate.serial_number) for plate in plates" required="true" />
                <option value=" ">----------</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>



        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="input-readonly" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Plate Type: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-readonly" value="{{selectedPlate.item.plate_types_id}}" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
```

if I do `selectedPlate.item.plate_type_id` it just works, and returns `1` in this case, But can I get the `name` attribute instead of the `id` or using the `id` to get to the `name`

I have tried something like this

`selectedPlate.item.plate_type_id.name` But it does not work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two options to get the plate name by id:

- Transform `"plateTypes"` array to an object indexed by the `id` property. Then in the template you could get the name like that:

  ```
  plateTypes[selectedPlate.item.plate_type_id].name
  ```
- Write an utility function that, given an `id`, search in `plateTypes`. Then in the template you would get the name like that:

  ```
  getPlateType(selectedPlate.item.plate_type_id).name
  ```

Comment: I have gave this a try, But I guess I am doing something wrong. Could you please provide a sample code, perhaps a jsfiddle demo. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yep, wait a moment. By the way, as you want to get the plate name given an id, I assume the ids in `PlateTypes` are unique, aren't they?

Comment: the id's are unique indeed. But, I want to get the `plate_type` name and not the `plate` name, because the `plate` table does not have `name` attribute.  So the name of `platetype` with `id` 1 is now `Sibyl Streich`

Comment: Does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/ewboxb54/) correspond to what you need?

Comment: I know this is becoming very embarrassing, But I am trying to figure out a way to assign this the API call `plateTypes`  Here is my way                                                                                                                                                      `$scope.typesById = {};

     var  plateTypes =  PlateTypesFactory.query(function(platetypes){
      $scope.platetypes = platetypes;

    });

      plateTypes.forEach(function (type) {
        $scope.typesById[type.id] = type;
    });`   // I get an error plateTypes.forEach is not a function